# A contravariant functor taking colimits to limits is representable.

Tags: category-theory

If $F$ is a contravariant functor from $Sets$ to $Sets$. And for any functor $H: I \to Sets$ that has a colimit $C$ we have $F(C)$ is a limit for $F \circ H: I ^{op} \to Sets $. Show that $F$ is representable.

I have no idea how to start. I think I should take some $I$ and $H$ and using the colimit of it as a represent. But I have no idea how to find such $I$ or $H$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, start with a representable functor $\mathbf{Set}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$. Can you figure out how to recover the representing object from just the functor? Then apply this procedure to your contravariant functor.

Comment: @ZhenLin Not really... Since I just start category theory, I can't even come up with an example of a representable functor from $Set ^{op } \to Set$ now..

Comment: Anther hint:  $Set$ has a property that every object of it is a colimit of particularly simple objects.

Comment: @DimitriChikhladze Do you mean every object is the colimit of the functor sending one point to that object?

Comment: "I can't even come up with an example of a representable functor" - perhaps it is better to look at examples first (in any book on category theory, or at Wikipedia for instance) before solving this exercise.

Comment: No, i mean that every object in Set is a colimit of a diagram objects in which are particularly simple. In other words, every set is a colimit of particularly simple sets.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Not OP, but it should be that if $L$ is the left adjoint of $F$, then the representing object is $L(\{\ast\})$ where $\{\ast\}$ is the set with 1 element?

Comment: Do I need to use the adjoint functor theorem in this problem?

Comment: No, you do not need the adjoint functor theorem. Just go look at some examples first!